# access a web service in Iphone

Tags: iphone

I have a wsdl link of my web service.and i want yo consume this web service in my iphone application. this web service is a JAX-WS service.Please guide me the best way to use this web service.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [wsdl2objc](http://code.google.com/p/wsdl2objc/). It is a code generation utility that create all the stub classes needed to access Web Services. I had to modify the templates in order to obtain exactly the SOAP envelope needed by our web services, but it was not difficult at all.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Apple's [Event Driven XML Programming guide](http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/XMLParsing/XMLParsing.html)